# Extracting Coefficients from a List of Sines

Tags: list-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

I want to extract the coefficients from the following list:

```
list={16.2219 Sin[16.2219 t], 6.60924 Sin[6.60924 t], 13.927 Sin[
13.927 t], 2.91309 Sin[2.91309 t]}
```

The only way I've found it to work is if I put the exact expression for Sin in the following manner,

```
Coefficient[list[[1]], Sin[16.2219]]
```

My actual list is very long and each Sin has a different argument. In a perfect world I would like to do,

```
coefs = Table[Coefficient[list[[i]],Sin[t]],{i,1,Length[list]}]
```

Anyone have experience with this? Thanks!

Comment: Iterate over `Variables[list]`.

Comment: `Coefficient[#, #2] & @@@ Thread@{list, Variables /@ list}`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1zlFL.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fairly general approach is to use pattern matching, but always look at the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FullForm.html) of mathematical expressions before you write your patterns or you may be surprised.

```
Cases[list, x_*_Sin :> x]
```

> ```
> {16.2219, 6.60924, 13.927, 2.91309}
> ```

For the particular case you can also use:

```
list /. _Sin -> 1
```

> ```
> {16.2219, 6.60924, 13.927, 2.91309}
> ```

Or simply extract the parts you want (which rhermans already showed):

```
First /@ list
```

> ```
> {16.2219, 6.60924, 13.927, 2.91309}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

This might not be the standard solution, but anyways. If all elements have exactly the form $a\sin(at)$ with $a>0$, you could do

```
Sqrt[D[list, t] /. t -> 0]
```

> ```
> {16.2219, 6.60924, 13.927, 2.91309}
> ```

since $D(a\sin(at))=a^2\cos(at)$ which equals $a^2$ for $t=0$.

Comment: I gladly admit that the other solution(s) proposed is better than this. What is the standard then, should I delete it?

Comment: welcome to Mathematica.SE. I suggest you keep the answer. It is an interesting outside-the-box approach. (+1)

Comment: @kguler Thank you very much for your kind comment and information.

Answer (score 3):

```
#[[1]] & /@ list
```

also known as

```
First /@ list
```

(as pointed bt @Mr.Wizard).

Or (credit to  @DanielLichtblau)

```
First@(#/Variables[#]) & /@ list
```

> ```
> {16.2219, 6.60924, 13.927, 2.91309}
> ```

Comment: FYI: `#[[1]] & /@ list` would be better written as `list[[All, 1]]`. +1 nevertheless

Answer (score 3):

If you need to use `Coefficient` you can do

```
Coefficient[list /. Sin[_] :> z, z]
(* {16.2219,6.60924,13.927,2.91309} *)
```

If not, many alternatives, including

```
list /. Sin -> (1 &)
(* {16.2219,6.60924,13.927,2.91309} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try these:

```
list /. Sin[__] :> Sin[\[Pi]/2]

Level[list, {2}][[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]]

DeleteCases[list, Sin[__], -1]

Replace[list, _ -> \[Pi]/2, {3}]

(*{16.2219, 6.60924, 13.927, 2.91309}*)
```