# How can I find the coefficient of some function of varying inputs in a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, coefficients

I have a list

```
klist={4 K[{1}, {1}], K[{2}, {2}], (2 K[{2}, {1, 1}])/("Ndim")}
```

where `K[{list_1}, {list_2}]` is some function. I want to obtain the list

```
coef = {4, 1, 2/"Ndim"}.
```

The content of the function `K` is not important to me when determining coef. I have tried the command `Coefficient`, but I do not know if there is some kind of placeholder I can use to communicate that I want to extract what proceeds `K`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting Coefficients from a List of Sines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63335/extracting-coefficients-from-a-list-of-sines) Namely, `klist /. K[__] :> 1`.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I tried other variations but did not know about the double underscore!